# Resource for in depth "model checking" for multiple linear regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients

I'm looking for a book or resource that goes really in depth on the model checking and diagnostics for the multiple linear regression.  Basically it goes into a lot of depth on how model assumption violations affect the biasedness and variance of coefficient estimates, how it changes t-statistics and p-values, how it changes the confidence/prediction intervals, how it changes interpreting and inferencing using the model, how it changes adjusted R2 and R2, etc...  I'm looking for it to cover what happens when Y | X is not normal, when there is heteroskedasticity, when we have collinearity, when we have non independent observations, etc...

Thanks!

Comment: I mean, those assumptions can be violated in a variety of ways, each of which may affect the test statistics in different ways.  I'm not sure of a single resource which addresses each of these.  Have you considered performing some simulations?

Comment: any assumption violation invalidates inference. how so, it depends on hundreds of things

Comment: I think that Seber & Lee, *Linear Regression Analysis*, is a good starting point.

Comment: Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies* comes to mind